# How can I set a class to a HTML element which is created by custom tooltip function?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I have developed a linechart which is enriched with a custom tooltip function. For my set of skills I came quiet far using SO as resource, but now I struggle with the last step.

I want to set a class to the html element (table) in order to be able to modify the style of the table, more particular to insert border-spacing and align left/right.

How to achieve a class being added to the html object?

[image]

**This is the related part in the custom tooltip function:**

```
      // Set Text
      if (tooltipModel.body) {
        var titleLines = tooltipModel.title || [];
        var bodyLines = tooltipModel.body.map(getBody);
        var innerHtml = '';

        titleLines.forEach(function(title) {
          innerHtml += '';
        });
        innerHtml += '';

        bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {
          var colors = tooltipModel.labelColors[i];
          var style = 'background:' + colors.backgroundColor;
          style += '; border-color:' + colors.borderColor;
          style += '; border-width: 2px';
          innerHtml += '<tr>';
          innerHtml += '<td>' + 'Date' + '</td>';
          innerHtml += '<td>' + 'Date_Variable' + '</td></tr>';
          innerHtml += '<tr>';
          innerHtml += '<td>' + 'Venue' + '</td>';
          innerHtml += '<td>' + 'Venue_variable' + '</td></tr>';
          innerHtml += '<tr>';
          innerHtml += '<td>' + 'Round' + '</td>';
          innerHtml += '<td>' + 'Round_variable' + '</td></tr>';
          innerHtml += '<tr>';
          innerHtml += '<td>' + 'Team1' + '</td>';
          innerHtml += '<td>' + 'Team1_variable' + '</td></tr>';
          innerHtml += '<tr>';
          innerHtml += '<td>' + 'Team2' + '</td>';
          innerHtml += '<td>' + 'Team2_variable' + '</td></tr>';
          innerHtml += '<tr>';
          innerHtml += '<td>' + 'Result' + '</td>';
          innerHtml += '<td>' + 'Result_variable' + '</td></tr>';
        });
        innerHtml += '</tbody>';

        var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');
        tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
      }
```

In advance thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems like you can add a class name to the table inside `#chartjs-tooltip` directly by `document.querySelector("#chartjs-tooltip > table").classList.add("[Your Class]")`

or, since you have already had `var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');`, just add `tableRoot.classList.add("[Your Class]")` below.

Answer (score 0):

may be a usefull, instead a add or remove a toggle principle:

```js
var toggleRed = function() {
  document.querySelector('#sss').classList.toggle('red-box');
}
```

```css
.box {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.red-box {
  background-color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<div id="sss" class="box"></div>

<button onclick="toggleRed()">toggle red</button>
```